# Difference between associated and raw values in swift enumerations

Tags: swift, enums, enumeration

Swift enumerations have both associated and raw values. But the use cases of these values is not clear to me. So I would really appreciate if anyone can explain the difference between the associated and raw values, an example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Raw values are for when every case in the enumeration is represented by a compile-time-set value.  The are akin to constants, i.e.

```
let A = 0
let B = 1
```

is similar to:

```
enum E: Int {
    case A  // if you don't specify, IntegerLiteralConvertible-based enums start at 0
    case B
}
```

So, `A` has a fixed raw value of `0`, `B` of `1` etc set at compile time.  They all have to be the same type (the type of the raw value is for the whole enum, not each individual case).  They can only be literal-convertible strings, characters or numbers.  And they all have to be *distinct* (no two enums can have the same raw value).

Associated values are more like variables, associated with *one* of the enumeration cases:

```
enum E {
    case A(Int)
    case B
    case C(String)
}
```

Here, `A` now has an associated `Int` that can hold *any* integer value.  `B` on the other hand, has no associated value.  And `C` has an associated `String`.  Associated types can be of any type, not just strings or numbers.

Any given value of type `E` will only ever hold one of the associated types, i.e. either an `Int` if the enum is an `A`, or a `String` if the enum is a `C`.  It only needs enough space for the bigger of the two.  Types like this are sometimes referred to as "discriminated unions" – a union being a variable that can hold multiple different types, but you know (from the enum case) which one it is holding.

They can even be generic.  The most common example of which is `Optional`, which is defined like this:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case .Some(T)
    case .None
}
```

Comment: if it's like: `case A(orderNumber: Int, account:String)` what would the associated type be then? a tuple on Int, String?

Comment: @Honey “Define an enumeration type called Barcode, which can take either a value of upc with an associated value of type (Int, Int, Int, Int), or a value of qrCode with an associated value of type String.”

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html

Answer (score 3):

**Swift Enum raw vs associated values**

[[Swift types]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219141/4770877)

`Enumerations` or `Enum` allows you to create a finite set of values and enum variable references on a **single** value from the set

[image]

In Swift, an enum cannot have both **raw values** and **associated values** at the same time.

### Raw Values

```
enum Color: String {
    case white = "#ffffff"
    case black = "#000000"
}
```

A "raw value" is an unique identifier of a type. It means that you are able to construct your type by ID. For example:

```
XCTAssertEqual(Color.white, Color(rawValue: "#ffffff"))
```

To get raw value use

```
Color.white.rawValue
```

### Associated Values

```
enum Color {
    case white
    case black
    
    case custom(hex: String)
}
```

Swift's "associated values" allows you to add additional information into enum that can be defined dynamically. Please note when we introduce "associated values", we omit the "raw values" and add a type annotation. This makes it impossible to use the "raw value" to reconstruct your type, because it is now set up dynamically.

You can read the "associated value" as follows:

```
let myColor = Color.custom(hex: "#ff00ff")
    
switch myColor {
case .custom(let hex):
    print("custom color hex:\(hex)") //#ff00ff
case .white:
    print("white color")
case .black:
    print("black color")
}
```

Good example of `Associated Value` enum is `Result`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66413003/4770877)

Please note that Objective-C does not support Swift's enum(except Int-bound)

**Compare value in enum**

raw enum

```
if case .error = someResult {
    //some logic
}
```

associated enum

```
if case .success(let result) = someResult, result == "ok" {
    //some logic
}
```

[[Swift change Enum associated value]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586527/4770877)

[[Swift indirect enum]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317241/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

Answers by @Airspeed Velocity and @yoAlex5 explain the difference well, but they state that

> enums can have **either** associated **either** raw values.

This is not so for Swift 4 and 5.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45954779) is a good illustration on for having them both in one enum. You'll need default values for raw value initialiser, of course.