# Structs that refer to each other in Swift 3

Tags: swift, struct

I have two CoreData entities which have one to one relationship. I want to create structs based on this entities.
**My code:**

```
struct DetailedPin {
     var pin: Pin?
}

struct Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?  
}
```

But I got an error: `Value type 'DetailedPin' cannot have a stored property that references itself`. And the same error for `Pin` struct. How can I handle this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191372/reference-cycles-with-value-types

Comment: Please mark the accepted answer

Comment: Just make it a class instead of struct?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that an `Optional` stores its `Wrapped` value inline (see [Mike Ash's fantastic blog post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-01-exploring-swift-memory-layout-part-ii.html) for more info about this) – meaning that an `Optional` instance (regardless of whether it is `nil` or not) will occupy at least the same amount of memory as the type you wish to store in its `.some` case (the `Wrapped` type).

Thus, as your `Pin` struct has a property of type `DetailedPin?`, and `DetailedPin` has a property of type `Pin?`, infinite storage would be required in order to store these values inline.

The solution therefore is simply to add a layer of indirection. One way of doing this would be to make `Pin` and/or `DetailedPin` a reference type (i.e a `class`) as [@dfri has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40772696/2976878).

However, if you wish to keep the value semantics of `Pin` and `DetailedPin`, one option would be to create a wrapper type backed by a class instance to provide the necessary indirection:

```
/// Provides indirection for a given instance.
/// For value types, value semantics are preserved.
struct Indirect<T> {

  // Class wrapper to provide the actual indirection.
  private final class Wrapper {

    var value: T

    init(_ value: T) {
      self.value = value
    }
  }

  private var wrapper: Wrapper

  init(_ value: T) {
    wrapper = Wrapper(value)
  }

  var value: T {
    get {
      return wrapper.value
    }
    set {
      // Upon mutation of value, if the wrapper class instance is unique,
      // mutate the underlying value directly.
      // Otherwise, create a new instance.
      if isKnownUniquelyReferenced(&wrapper) {
        wrapper.value = newValue
      } else {
        wrapper = Wrapper(newValue)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can now just use the `Indirect` wrapper for one (or both) of your structs properties:

```
struct DetailedPin {
  private var _pin = Indirect<Pin?>(nil)

  // Convenience computed property to avoid having to say ".value" everywhere.
  var pin: Pin? {
    get { return _pin.value }
    set { _pin.value = newValue }
  }
}

struct Pin {
  var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
  var foo: String
}

var d = DetailedPin()
var p = Pin(detailedPin: d, foo: "foo")
d.pin = p

// testing that value semantics are preserved...
var d1 = d
d1.pin?.foo = "bar"

print(d.pin?.foo as Any) // Optional("foo")
print(d1.pin?.foo as Any) // Optional("bar")
```

Comment: Great answer! (And great blog post link, had not seen that before :)

Comment: I was going through your answer and why does this work? Arrays are structures in swift as well.
`struct DetailedPin {
     var pin: [Pin]?
}

struct Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?  
}`

Comment: @Rikh Although `Array` is a structure, it's of fixed size. The actual contents of the array is stored indirectly, and is copied upon mutation in order to preserve value semantics.

Answer (score 8):

A one to one relationship between two entities is only valid if at least one of the connections between these entities is of *reference* type; for two pure value types, their one to one relationsship will become a recursive one.

Say you create an object of the value type `DetailedPin`. It contains an instance property (`pin`) of the value type `Pin`, which means this instance property is *part of the value* that is the instance of `DetailedPin`. Now, the instance property `pin` of and instance of `DetailedPin`, is of the value type `Pin`, which itself contains an instance property (`detailedPin`) of value type `DetailedPin`. This instance member `detailedPin` is, again, _a part of the value that is the instance `pin`), but again, `detailedPin` itself owns a value of type `pin`, and so the recursive dance continues ...

You can circumvent this by turning one of your structures into a reference type (`class`):

```
struct DetailedPin {
   var pin: Pin?
}

class Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
}

// or
class DetailedPin {
   var pin: Pin?
}

struct Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
}
```

Note that the recursive relationship covered above is not directly related to ARC (automatic reference counting) or strong reference cycles, but the fact that the value of a value type instance is the instance itself and the *value* of all value type (sub-)properties it contains (as well as the *reference* to all reference type (sub-)properties it contains).

Just take care if you choose to let both your one to one entities be reference types: in this case you must make sure that one of the references between the two types are `weak`. E.g.:

```
class DetailedPin {
    weak var pin: Pin?
}

class Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
}

// or
class DetailedPin {
    var pin: Pin?
}

class Pin {
    weak var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
}
```

In case you leave out `weak` above (i.e., let both refer to each other by the default strong references), you will have a strong reference cycle between the two instances referring to each other

```
class DetailedPin {
    var pin: Pin?
    deinit { print("DetailedPin instance deinitialized") }
}

class Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
    deinit { print("Pin instance deinitialized") }
}

func foo() {
    let pin = Pin()
    let detailedPin = DetailedPin()
    pin.detailedPin = detailedPin
    detailedPin.pin = pin
}

foo() // no deinit called
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned here: [indirect enums and structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533006/indirect-enums-and-structs), an elegant solution could be to wrap your reference inside an enum with an `indirect` case.

In you example, it would give this:

```
enum ReferencePin {
  case none
  indirect case pin(Pin)
}

struct DetailedPin {
     var pin: ReferencePin
}

struct Pin {
    var detailedPin: DetailedPin?
}
```

or directly, depending on your needs:

```
enum ReferencePin {
  case none
  indirect case pin(Pin)
}

struct Pin {
    var otherPin: ReferencePin
}
```

Beyond of my understanding, `indirect` tells the compiler there is a recursion in your enum, and it should *insert the necessary layer of indirection*.

Answer (score 3):

This should accomplish what you need:

```swift
struct DetailedPin {
    private var _pin: Any?

    var pin: Pin? {
        get {
            return _pin as? Pin
        }
        set {
            _pin = newValue
        }
    }
}

struct Pin {
    private var _detailedPin: Any?

    var detailedPin: DetailedPin? {
        get {
            return _detailedPin as? DetailedPin
        }
        set {
            _detailedPin = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
var pin = Pin()
var detailedPin = DetailedPin()

pin.detailedPin = detailedPin
```