# Convert a Objective C Self Referential Struct to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

Self referential Structs are possible in objective C. Eg:

```
typedef struct Sample {
    struct Sample* first;
    struct Sample* second;
    struct Sample* third;
} SampleStruct;
```

The swift conversion looks something like

```
struct Sample {
    var first: Sample?
    var second: Sample?
    var third: Sample?
}
typealias SampleStruct = Sample
```

But it throws a compiler error saying "Value type 'Sample' cannot have a stored property that references itself".

How do i convert the self referential struct to swift?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771706/structs-that-refer-to-each-other-in-swift-3

Comment: Have you considered using a class instead?

Comment: You should use class in this case. Struct cant do this as error message says.

Answer (score 3):

You know you cannot define this sort of struct in Objective-C.

```
typedef struct Sample {
    struct Sample first;
    struct Sample second;
    struct Sample third;
} SampleStruct;
```

(Swift adds a hidden `isNil...` field for each Optional, but it's not a big difference.)

If you want to define an exact equivalent to your Objective-C code, you need to use pointers, as in the original code.

```
struct Sample {
    var first: UnsafeMutablePointer<Sample>?
    var second: UnsafeMutablePointer<Sample>?
    var third: UnsafeMutablePointer<Sample>?
}
```

Better consider using class as commented.