# Swift 5 Result type

Tags: swift, swift5

In Swift 5 Apple introduced `Result` type. It's generic enum with two cases:

```
public enum Result<Success, Failure: Error> {
    case success(Success), failure(Failure)
}
```

Personally I used to two separate completions in network calls `success: Completion` and `failure: Completion`, but from what I see now, Apple pushing us to use single completion with `Result` type and then inside perform switch. So what are advantages of this approach with `Result`? Because in a lot of cases I can just omit error handling and don't write this `switch`. Thanks.

Comment: Imo switching everywhere will be painful. I'd still stick to the two completions handler. Flow of control is a lot clearer that way.

Comment: It's not mandatory to use `Result`. You can do what you want. But I'm sure many, many people (like myself) will appreciate it and take advantage of it.

Comment: Not being compatible with Objective-C can be an issue. Rewriting all your code, that's useless. Advantage: When you are doing same code and not factorize it elsewhere, like "reshowing some stuff, enabling user interaction, etc." in case of failure AND success.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn’t omit cases when `Result` is `failure`. You shouldn’t do it with `Result` and you shouldn’t do it with your closure for failure. You should **handle errors**.

Anyway, `Result` type was introduced for simplifing completion handlers. You can have single closure for handling success or failure (primary-opinion based if two separate closures are better or not). Also `Result` is designed for error handling. You can simply create your own `enum` conforming to `Error` and then you can create your own error cases.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5 introduced `Result<Success, Failure>` `associated value` enumeration[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57109262/4770877) It means that your result can be either `success` or `failure` with additional info(success result or error object). Good practice is to manage error case and success case as atomic task.

Advantages:

- Result is a single/general(generic)/full type which can be used for all yes/no cases
- Not optional type
- Forces consumers to check all cases

```
public enum Result<Success, Failure>  {
    case success(Success)
    case failure(Failure)
}
```

To use it

```
//create
func foo() -> Result<String, Error> {
    //logic
    if ok {
        return .success("Hello World")
    } else {
        return .failure(.someError)
    }
}

//read
func bar() {
    let result = foo()
    switch result {
    case .success(let someString):
        //success logic
    case .failure(let error):
        //fail logic
    }
}
```