# Why we cannot retrieve rawValue from Enums with associated values?

Tags: swift, enums

Here is my enum

```
enum associatedEnums {
case someIntHere(Int)
case someStrHere(String)
```

}

```
var associatedEnumsInst = associatedEnums.someStrHere("String here")
```

I am able to print using

```
print(associatedEnumsInst)
```

I get the output as `someStrHere("String here")`

If i try to print

```
print(associatedEnumsInst.rawValue)
```

I get this error: value of type 'associatedEnums' has no member 'rawValue'

I am expecting a output like this `"String here"`

I am aware that i can do something like this

```
switch associatedEnumsInst{
case .someIntHere(let val) : print(val)
case .someStrHere(let val) : print(val)
}
```

But i wanna get the value without using switch statement and only using rawValue property of enums. Is it possible?

Comment: Note the [swift4] tag is only for questions specifically about a *change* in the language for that version, which this is not. The [swift] tag is for general language questions, which this is. I have edited out the [swift4] tag again.

Comment: Enums with associated values have no rawValue. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171814/can-associated-values-and-raw-values-coexist-in-swift-enumeration.

Comment: You can add `rawValue: Any` as a computed property but this approach has its own problem: how can you tell the data type and meaning of this `rawValue`? Is it an `Int` or a `String`? What case was it associated with? By the time you add code to figure out these things, the solution is no better (or even worse) than the `switch` statement approach.