# How can achieve Enum to have a arguments on a case

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum which has a String raw value. I want one of the cases get a string as input and return a string which that input. How can I achieve this?

```
public enum PredictTypes: String {
    case favtasks = "isFav == YES"
    case importtanttasks = "isImportant == YES"
    case alltasks = ""
    case customList(listName: String) = "listName == \(listName)"
}
```

As I searched I found some posts but can't understand for my case:

[Can associated values and raw values coexist in Swift enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171814/can-associated-values-and-raw-values-coexist-in-swift-enumeration)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your enum like this:

```
public enum PredictTypes {
    case favtasks
    case importanttasks
    case alltasks
    case customList(listName: String)

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .favtasks: return "isFav == YES"
        case .importanttasks: return "isImportant == YES"
        case .alltasks: return ""
        case .customList(let listName): return "listName == \(listName)"
        }
    }
}
```